# Is it commonly observed that one bad comment can lead to a flurry of downvotes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I recently posted an answer which received a negative comment from someone, who was, in fact, not fully informed. **Getting negative comments isn't really a big deal**, (Let's face it: stack overflow is famous for its negative comments.) but it's an observation of mine that strongly worded negative comments (*By which I mean stuff like: "That's absolutely wrong!" or "That doesn't help, it hurts!" or "That's not correct at all!" but not necessarily outright hostile.*)  seem lead others to quickly downvote after *summarily* reading the comment. There was another comment in response, which (correctly) disagreed with the negative comment and provided correction. I deleted my answer because I didn't want to lose rep, but I can't help but think that reactionary vote casting doesn't benefit the site.

Like the title says, have others observed this trend?

Comment: "Negative comment" as in a comment (in the area that I'm typing in), or "negative comment" as in an answer that was poorly received?

Comment: @Makoto as in a comment in the area we're typing.

Comment: Any "this is wrong!" kind of comment is only a *hint* that there is something wrong with an answer.  If it gets a flurry of DVs then you can be 90% sure that it is wrong.  If such a comment doesn't suggest an improvement then you can always flag it as "not constructive" and a mod will delete it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not observed this trend. But even if I had, I would say it is simply a fundamental failing of a system that allows anyone with a token amount of reputation to cast a vote—in other words, a democracy.

It works the other way, too. Plenty of people see an answer that looks *superficially* good and upvote it. No matter that it is outright wrong, contains obsolete information, or recommends a cure that is worse than the disease ("just add `DoEvents` inside of your loop!"). Plenty of these voters don't have the requisite knowledge to judge what a good, accurate, and complete answer is. At *best*, they think to themselves, "sounds good!", and cast an upvote. At worst, they vote based on the user who wrote the post.

So it kind of makes sense that someone who has little background on which to judge an answer's merits would be easily swayed by a strongly-worded comment. I don't know if it is fair to call this "reactionary vote casting". In some sense, all vote casting is reactionary: you are reacting to the accuracy and usefulness of the post.

The real problem is *wrong* vote casting. But we don't really have such a notion here—and can't. It is not for one user to judge the veracity of another's vote, so long as they follow the basic ground rules (no sock puppetry, no serial voting, etc.). One person's vote is—on its face—just as valuable as another person's vote. We simply have to hope that an appropriate score will eventually shake out in the end. As such, don't be shy with casting your own votes when you have a conviction that something is useful/correct or useless/wrong!

As for your choice to delete the answer because you didn't want to lose rep, I would strongly advise you to rethink this strategy. I understand that it sucks to lose rep, but they're just imaginary Internet points. If you are convinced that your answer is accurate and useful, then you should leave it visible. Trust that you will be vindicated in the end by future upvotes. An upvote is worth +10, but a downvote is only worth −2, so the odds are on your side. Really, the only time you should delete an answer that is attracting downvotes is because you have seen the error of your ways and decided either that you don't want to fix the answer or see that someone else has already posted a better answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it commonly observed that one bad comment can lead to a flurry of downvotes?

No it isn't.

One misinformed comment may lead to one downvote but generally it rarely ever goes further than that.

One comment stating that an answer is wrong isn't creating downvotes, it is giving you a bit of an explanation as to why you may be receiving multiple downvotes. From my own experience, this comment tends to be correct also - either I've misread the question or just misunderstood something entirely.